# How do I get `matplotlib` 2's new defaults in `matplotlib` 1.5?

Tags: matplotlib

I've been reading the [upcoming changes](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/dflt_style_changes.html) in `matplotlib` 2's default styles with some interest but I expect it'll be a while until our sysadmins upgrade us. In the meantime, I thought I'd try to sort of backport the changes to `matplotlib` 1.5, which is what we have, using the defaults in [`matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

For example, to get the new colormap `viridis` and change the interpolation method, I've added

```
image.cmap : viridis
image.interpolation : none
```

Is there a resource from which I can extract all the other changes too (or as many as possible)?  I'm currently trying to infer them manually from [the page listing the changes](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/dflt_style_changes.html).  Simply copying [`matplotlibrc.template`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/matplotlibrc.template) from the `matplotlib` 2 gave me a huge whack of errors.